# ¿Cómo es la forma correcta de mover los bloques html en css?

Tags: html, css

Tengo una duda, la cual trata de que he visto a un amigo mío, que cuando mueve los bloques de html para posicionarlos en la forma que lo ve conveniente, usa el "Padding" y "Margin", en cambio yo coloco "position" a mis bloques y después lo muevo con las propiedades "top", "bottom", "rigth" y "left" en css, estoy iniciandome en la programación web y quisiera que alguien me aclare mi duda, gracias por su atención y sus ayuda de antemano :D.

Comment: Aunado a eso puedes [leer sobre `padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/padding) y acá [sobre `margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

Comment: Entonces, la respuesta sería que la forma que mi amigo está usando es la correcta y debo investigar a como usar correctamente los padding, margin y las posiciones, cierto?.

Comment: *No necesariamente*, de hecho te estoy enlazando esos 3 links para que le des una repasada a los 3 temas por que no es que elijas uno sobre otro (*sin mayor argumento*), la respuesta corta es depende que necesites hacer, la respuesta larga es que cheques la teoría completa para que asimiles cuando una y cuando otra forma

Comment: Voy a darle una revisada a los links, de todas maneras gracias por tu ayuda, voy a ponerlo en práctica.